# LVDS rise/fall time measurements - confused

Tags: measurement, lvds, rise-time

In a document I found they mention that the rise/fall times are measured over 20-80% of the signal. They mention that the common mode is 1.2V with a output voltage swing of 350mV.

This all makes sense, but when they calculate the 20-80% they are using the differential peak to peak numbers, so they use -350mV to +350mV.

I thought you would just take the swing of 350mV and use 20-80% of that. I understand the P-N and (-(P-N) would be between -350mV and +350mV, but isn't each signal only swinging 350mV?

Why use 700mV swing?

I have captured a few photos as a reference.

[image: LVDS Output Levels]

[image: Measuring rise and fall times]

Comment: Because 700 mV is the differential voltage swing, which is what you really care about.  And it's also a definition issue - this is way LVDS defines its rise and fall times.

Comment: It should give you the same result. Each individual signal has the same rise/fall times.

Comment: @KevinWhite. I am trying to convert it to slew rate and the source lists it as a rise time (600ps) where the load lists it as a slew rate between .6V/ns to 4V/ns. So if I take 20-80% of the differential peak instead of the voltage swing, I will get two different answers

Comment: @Matty - agreed if you take it as a specific slew rate (in v/ns) the result will be different. However, If you calculate it as 20-80% using the appropriate voltage limits for 0-100% the two calculations will be the same as the differential voltage range is double that of each individual signal.

Comment: @KevinWhite. So as a real life example, my receiver is specifying a rising/falling edge rate as .4V/ns to 6V/ns as measured from -150mV to +150mV centered on the differential crossing. My source is spec'd at 600ps at 20-80% of the LVDS waveform. So do I convert my rise/fall time of my source to slew rate or the slew rate of my receiver to edge rate?